# Regarding performane of Hashmap while putting ten thousand objects in it

Tags: java, dictionary

I am a new bie to the world of Java,I just want to know the default size of Hash Map is 10 and it expands itself on the basis of load factor that is 0.75 then collisions take place and an new array of linked list get created and all the shuffling take place.

But my query is that suppose what is the performance of Map when I will put 10,000 objects in it,

for ex

```
  Map map=new HashMap();
```

How can I put 10,000 object ,have to follow any for loop for that please advise

```
for(1=0;1<=10,000,i++)
{
}
```

and second what impact would be there on performance and also what impact on the performance of map while putting the objects also.

Comment: It all depends on your hashing function. The more distributed the hashcodes it produces the faster your map; in the perfect case it won't degrade at all... See [Universal Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).

Comment: If you know there will be 10.000 items, you can use the [`HashMap(int initialCapacity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap(int)) constructor to avoid the resizing while inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can loop and put each object at a time to hashmap..

You can use HashMap(int initialCapacity) with some higher value for initialCapacity..since you know there would be 10000 objects...

Performance of retrieval from hash map depends on your objects hashcode() implementation...

More distinct values returned by hashcode for different objects will distribute objects evenly in various buckets...this leads to faster retrieval time...

Please see how hashmap works which will give you some idea:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html